# How to open local HTML files in iPhone browsers?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone having iOS 15.02. In the Files directory, there is an HTML file. I would like to open the file in a browser and when I click on the file and open it in Chrome, I receive the following message and can't open it.

> Chrome cannot handle this link.
> file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../tmp/drivekit/GDKGenoaContentProvider/test.html

Could you please help me with what is the cause of the above message? Are there any settings that I need to do to open the HTML files?

Answer (score -1):

i think the possible and easy means of viewing ***html*** files on your ***iphone*** is by having to download an application called **HTML VIEWER Q**.

You can view and download the application from : -
[1]: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/html-viewer-q/id810042973

Comment: I think the question is not about viewing source code but about rendering it on a browser on an iPhone, hence the downvote.